# When use subdomain in Flask, how to access static files quoted in css url and js files used require.js?

Tags: css, flask, requirejs, subdomain

Flask static settings:

```
app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0], static_folder=None)
app.static_url_path = '/static'
app.static_folder = 'static'
app.add_url_rule(app.static_url_path + '/<path:filename>',
                 endpoint='static',
                 view_func=app.send_static_file)
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MuiiconSpread;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src:  url('../fonts/icons.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

JS

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '/static/plugins/jquery-3.3.1/jquery.min',
    },
});
```

While access the subdomain such as: `a.test.com`, the `icons.ttf` and `jquery.min.js` are 404 error.

When I add `subdomain='a'` in `add_url_rule` for static, everything will be fine. But it just matches `a.test.com`, while access `b.test.com` should change the same config to `subdomain='b'`.

How to fix it?

Comment: So, you want *all* subdomains to return the data?

Comment: Yes I Want What can i do ??

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.

Based on research, I understand that **Flask-CORS** is the best solution.

But for temporary fix, I have added below code in `__init__.py` file in the root folder.

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    if request.endpoint.startswith('static'):
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```